# Article URL in Blog format adds suffix to menu separator

Tags: menu-item, menu

Main navigation items are separators and all active navigation are sub-level menu items.

The Main menu works perfectly but, say, navigating to the blog all the active title links add a "-2" suffix to the separator in the URL.
See https://AlcoholJustice.org/blog

I cannot find an option switch or setting to remove this. There isn't a duplicate nor any reference anywhere of this suffix.

Please advise.

Comment: Would you mind including a screenshot, please? Once this issue is resolved, future researchers won't be able to reference the live site for context anymore.

Comment: If I hover each of the links in the page you provided the link for I can see most of them have the '-2' inserted as you describe. However there are some child links that do not show the '-2' suggesting this is not a global issue. Maybe see if you can spot a pattern between those that do and those that don't. The links for Alcohol Industry 101 , Dangerous Products and Californian Alcohol Policy are three examples.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your problem further I don't think the issue is with the Menu system as the page you provided with the Links is a Category List view which is getting its details from the Category not the Menu.

If you go to Content->Category and look at the list of Categories, next to the name of the Category is the Alias in Brackets and in there is the actual name used in your links. I suspect you will find a lot of them have a '-2' added to them from when you did a 'Save as Copy' or similar function to duplicate the Category.

I would go as far as to say your site is mostly made up of one Article per Category or Menu which is why you are getting confused. There are better ways to manage your content that will make managing your site a lot easier and more friendly to search engines. Essentially one category, say Blog, should have lots of Articles, not a category for each article.

Terry